# strange Kinect acceleration values with OpenNI and avin SensorKinect

Tags: kinect, openni

according to [1], I should be able to access Kinect accelerometer data with request 0x32, providing a buffer with 10 bytes. The accelerometer vector xyz values should be short ints at bytes 3 thru 8. As stated in the text (and as expected), with a horizontally, stationary camera, I should get values near 0 for both x and z, and about 981 for y. This would be g and would make sense. Instead, while y values are as expected, I get x and z values near 0xffff. Here's the code (i skipped error-checking for better readability):

```
const unsigned short VENDOR_ID_MSFT = 0x045e;
const unsigned short PRODUCT_ID_KINECT360_MOTOR = 0x02b0;

XN_USB_DEV_HANDLE deviceHandle = NULL;
const XnUSBConnectionString *paths = NULL;
XnUInt32 count;

xnUSBInit();
xnUSBEnumerateDevices( VENDOR_ID_MSFT, PRODUCT_ID_KINECT360_MOTOR, &paths, &count );
xnUSBOpenDeviceByPath( paths[0], &this->deviceHandle );

//init motor
xnUSBSendControl( this->deviceHandle, (XnUSBControlType) 0xc0, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, buf, sizeof( buf ), 0 );

XnStatus res;
XnUChar buf[10] = { 0 };
XnUInt32 size = 0;
//query motor data
xnUSBReceiveControl( this->deviceHandle, XN_USB_CONTROL_TYPE_VENDOR, 0x32, 0, 0, buf, sizeof( buf ), &size, 0 );

int accelCountX = (int) ( ( (short) buf[2] << 8 ) | buf[3] );
int accelCountY = (int) ( ( (short) buf[4] << 8 ) | buf[5] );
int accelCountZ = (int) ( ( (short) buf[6] << 8 ) | buf[7] );

std::cout << accelCountX << "/" << accelCountY << "/" << accelCountZ << std::endl;
```

The output shows values kind of like these:

> 65503/847/65516

Any idea, what the problem could be? Thanks!

[1] http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/nui16/motorControl.pdf

Comment: The problem may simply be that the feature was never properly supported. OpenNI was dropped by the original developer, and there's been no meaningful work (as of the last time I checked) since a 2.0 beta release. A few features that are said to be supported simply don't work. With luck someone will be able to suggest a code tweak, but keep in mind that an OpenNI bug could be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm aware of that. But I'm not sure, direct USB control kinda bypasses OpenNI afaik, plus those commands work well for the Kinect motor and status LED, so I doubt that an OpenNI bug might be the issue. I didn't try alternatives such as libusb to compare the results due to time constraints, but I expect the result to be the same. As for now, the issue is not critical for me but I would be interested. I'll report back when I've got more time to investigate, in the meantime I hope for someone sharing experiences.